# Trigger on ActivityMetric object

Tags: apex, trigger

Any suggestions that how to get the `ActivityMetric` object trigger coverage?

Actually, `ActivityMetric` fields are not writable except the BaseId and I have a trigger on an `ActivityMetri`c object which writes the latest activity data to the custom fields and activities are captured using Einstein activity capture feature.

Answer (score 0):

I've not any experience with this myself, but the documentation seems to say that this record is automatically created when an Event is created on a record. Create an Account, create an Event for that Account, and this trigger should fire.

Comment: Thanks, @DavidSchach. Yes, I have done this implementation and trigger fires but I was wondering, how would I write the test class as this object fields are not writable except the baseId

Comment: When you run the test inserting the Account and the Event, the object should create itself. If the system usually creates the record behind the scenes when not testing, then it will do so during tests as well. Just put your Event insertion BEFORE your Test.stoptest() statement and you'll be fine.

Comment: Following up @Mahwish - did this help?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can test this through a couple of "hacks". If your logic applies to a before insert trigger then we're in luck! Factor out the logic to a handler class and method.

For your test code, initialize the sObject, then put the insert in a `try catch` block.... in the catch block catch the exception. Granted, this is not asserting the logic, but you're getting code coverage on the trigger to deploy the trigger. To assert the actual logic run unit tests on the handler....

This is just a limitation of the platform, like pricebooks were a while ago.

OR, you can do `@seeAllData` on the test method.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question but just incase someone stumbles upon it.

You can populate read-only fields on objects by serializing and then deserializing them into a map and then reverse back to an object:

```
ActivityMetric am = new ActivityMetric(BaseId='003000000000000000');
Map<String, Object> amUntyped = (Map<String, Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(JSON.Serialize(am));
amUntyped.put('LastEmailDateTime',System.Now());
am = (ActivityMetric) JSON.Deserialize(JSON.serialize(amUntyped), ActivityMetric.class);
```

You cannot insert this into a database though.

To use this in a test class you should implement a framework, ideally Enterprise Architecture Patters/FFLIB but any old framework could work. For example a simple service:

```
Trigger ActivityMetricTrigger on ActivityMetric(events...) {
    if(Trigger.IsInsert) {
        ActivityMetricService.DoSomething(Trigger.New);
    }
}
```

This way in your test class you can do:

```
ActivityMetricService.DoSomething(new List<ActivityMetric>{am}
```

This gets you coverage for your service class. Then for trigger coverage you just insert an ActivityMetric record, you don't use an system.asserts in your trigger test as you are only looking for coverage. All of your asserts are in your ActivityMetricService Test.

Better yet is to use mocking like in [ApexMocks](https://github.com/apex-enterprise-patterns/fflib-apex-mocks).

Theres plenty of resources on the web for how to use ApexMocks.